# The use of "over" in cryptography (as in "a hash over the key")

Tags: terminology

This is the ultimate noob question.

When reading discussions of cryptography, I often come across phrases like these:

> ...calculates a hash ***over*** the primary key...
>
> ...a key derivation function ***over*** a static string...
>
> ...an HMAC ***over*** the *i*-th derived key...

Is "over" in these examples just a hip way to say "of"?

More concretely, is there *a real technical difference* between the sentences above and their counterparts below?

> ...calculates a hash ***of*** the primary key...
>
> ...a key derivation function ***of*** a static string...
>
> ...an HMAC ***of*** the *i*-th derived key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash (or MAC or signature) *over* something is a hash of that thing at an identifiable position, plus some other stuff. It's a hash of M=P+T+S where P is some prefix, T is the thing and S is some suffix, and there is an unambiguous way of decomposing M into P, T and S.

For example, a certificate of a website is a signature over the site's domain name and its public key. It isn't just a signature of the domain name or a signature of the public key: it's a signature of a compound message from which the domain name and the public key can be extracted.

A hash over something gives the same integrity guarantee as a hash of that thing: if the thing is replaced by a different thing, the hash won't be the same. It's a useful concept because a lot of data formats don't take a hash of just the thing you're talking about at a given time: the hashed message can contain other metadata and data that aren't that one thing. It's especially important with a signature because a signature over two pieces of data is stronger than a signature over each piece separately. Taking the example of certificates again, a signature over a domain name and another signature over a public key would not be very useful, but a signature over a domain name and another signature tie them together in a very useful way.

A hash/MAC/signature *over* something can also mean a deeper construction, such as a hash of a string containing (in an unambiguous way) a hash of etc. For example, a signature of a hash of a message containing a hash of a second message containing a hash of a thing is a signature over that thing, because it guarantees the authenticity of that thing just like a signature of the thing itself would.